# Why compiler gives the message "call of overloaded function is ambiguous" here in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am testing below code but compiler says following when I compile in C++11:

`error: call of overloaded ‘func_A(int)’ is ambiguous`

Could anyone give an explanation?

Here is the code:

```
template<typename T> class MC {
    public:
    void func_A(int a, T initvalue = T()) {}
    void func_A(int a) {}

    void func_B(int b, T) {}
    void func_B(int b) {}
};

int main(void) {
    MC<int> mc;
    mc.func_A(1);     // error: detects call of overloaded
    mc.func_A(1,2);   // OK

    mc.func_B(10);    // OK
    mc.func_B(10,11); // OK

    return 0;
}
```

The full compile message:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:12:16: error: call of overloaded ‘func_A(int)’ is ambiguous
     mc.func_A(1);
                ^
test.cpp:12:16: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:3:10: note: void MC<T>::func_A(int, T) [with T = int]
     void func_A(int a, T initvalue = T()) {}
          ^
test.cpp:4:10: note: void MC<T>::func_A(int) [with T = int]
     void func_A(int a) {}
          ^
```

Comment: How is it supposed to know if you intended it to default the second parameter, or use the second overload?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a member function:

```
void func_A(int a, T initvalue = T()) {}
```

that can be called like this:

```
mc.func_A(1);
```

Then you have an overloaded member function:

```
  void func_A(int a) {}
```

that can also be called like this:

```
 mc.func_A(1);
```

How could the compiler know which function you intend to call by that line? Answer: It can not. Such ambiguous function call is ill-formed. Solution: Remove either the overload or the default argument so that there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

```
void func_A(int a, T initvalue = T()) {} // (1)
void func_A(int a) {} // (2)
```

**1** can be called with

```
func_A (10, someT); // (a)
```

and

```
func_A (10); // (b)
```

while **2** can be called with

```
func_A (10); // (c)
```

There is no way for the compiler to tell **b** from **c**.